# Randomize Elements Positions Defined between "<" and ">" Symbols Using Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, list, random, shuffle

I am trying to randomize elements positions that are defined between "<" and ">" brackets, eg.
from this

```
<id:1 s= red> 
<id:2 s= blue> 
<id:3 s= green>
```

to this

```
<id:3 s= green> 
<id:1 s= red> 
<id:2 s= blue>
```

I put them in a list but can't match back the randomized list with the regex results. Here is what I got so far:

```
import re
from random import shuffle

a = open('data.txt', 'r')
s= a.read()
x = re.findall(r'\<([^>]+)', s)
shuffle(x)
f = re.sub(r'\<([^>]+)', x[0], s)


print(f)
```

Comment: Not sure why you need all the regex machinery, '<id:1 s= red>', etc. could be put into a list of strings, just shuffle that list of strings.

Comment: The data.txt file is way more complicated and has all types of byte and hexadecimal data, I am just trying to keep the problem simple.

Comment: OK fair enough but how would an answer to the simple problem solve the actual problem?

Comment: It is an regular expression search, reorder and replace question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making your attempt work:

```
x = re.findall(r'(<[^>]+)', s)
shuffle(x)
f = re.sub(r'(<[^>]+)', lambda _: x.pop(), s)
```

How I prefer to do it:

```
x = re.split(r'(<[^>]+)', s)
y = x[1::2]
shuffle(y)
x[1::2] = y
f = ''.join(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BCoMwEETv@xV7S0KLoF6KWH@ktEVJUlNiEhIF/XqbWBFKT8vszOxbt4y9NeXF@XVVg7N@RC9Aejugbw2PY9@GfpJSC4CAVySE1IpXOYZrjPMGIckiyU5PYtdl0i8vhGliAWDGlM6kMrzVmnpC69ujuZ8YOWNgsBPozEB@k2HqflO6HTre4rPCOXPWUbYVwXllRirZgQhOq/EPsERzvuVVVdwP2MJgX0Vz2cCEZG@rTPrjuLyuHw)